# Hole in tiles with GeoServer 2.18 (while it works in 2.13)

Tags: geoserver

I'm upgrading my system from GeoServer 2.13.0 to GeoServer 2.18.2 on docker using kartoza image.
All works fine just I have this issue with a raster layer based on several pyramidal rasters: I get holes on some tiles, not on all of them, and sometimes only on one color band, like in this picture:

[image: Tile with a problem]

```
2021-12-02 01:25:02,050 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /tefenua/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=tefenua%3Atht_img_2017_50cm&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=614&BBOX=-149.42840695381165%2C-17.520757913589478%2C-149.4201672077179%2C-17.5141704082489'; against '/web/**'
2021-12-02 01:25:02,050 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /tefenua/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=tefenua%3Atht_img_2017_50cm&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=614&BBOX=-149.42840695381165%2C-17.520757913589478%2C-149.4201672077179%2C-17.5141704082489'; against '/gwc/rest/web/**'
2021-12-02 01:25:02,050 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /tefenua/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=tefenua%3Atht_img_2017_50cm&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=614&BBOX=-149.42840695381165%2C-17.520757913589478%2C-149.4201672077179%2C-17.5141704082489'; against '/'
2021-12-02 01:25:02,051 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /tefenua/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=tefenua%3Atht_img_2017_50cm&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=614&BBOX=-149.42840695381165%2C-17.520757913589478%2C-149.4201672077179%2C-17.5141704082489'; against '/j_spring_security_check'
2021-12-02 01:25:02,051 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /tefenua/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=tefenua%3Atht_img_2017_50cm&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=614&BBOX=-149.42840695381165%2C-17.520757913589478%2C-149.4201672077179%2C-17.5141704082489'; against '/j_spring_security_check/'
2021-12-02 01:25:02,051 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /tefenua/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=tefenua%3Atht_img_2017_50cm&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=614&BBOX=-149.42840695381165%2C-17.520757913589478%2C-149.4201672077179%2C-17.5141704082489'; against '/j_spring_security_logout'
2021-12-02 01:25:02,051 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /tefenua/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=tefenua%3Atht_img_2017_50cm&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=614&BBOX=-149.42840695381165%2C-17.520757913589478%2C-149.4201672077179%2C-17.5141704082489'; against '/j_spring_security_logout/'
2021-12-02 01:25:02,051 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /tefenua/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=tefenua%3Atht_img_2017_50cm&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=614&BBOX=-149.42840695381165%2C-17.520757913589478%2C-149.4201672077179%2C-17.5141704082489'; against '/rest/**'
2021-12-02 01:25:02,051 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /tefenua/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=tefenua%3Atht_img_2017_50cm&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=614&BBOX=-149.42840695381165%2C-17.520757913589478%2C-149.4201672077179%2C-17.5141704082489'; against '/gwc/rest/**'
2021-12-02 01:25:02,051 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /tefenua/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=tefenua%3Atht_img_2017_50cm&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=614&BBOX=-149.42840695381165%2C-17.520757913589478%2C-149.4201672077179%2C-17.5141704082489'; against '/**'
2021-12-02 01:25:02,051 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Request matched by universal pattern '/**'
2021-12-02 01:25:02,051 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /tefenua/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=tefenua%3Atht_img_2017_50cm&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=614&BBOX=-149.42840695381165%2C-17.520757913589478%2C-149.4201672077179%2C-17.5141704082489 with /**
2021-12-02 01:25:02,051 DEBUG [org.geoserver.monitor] - Testing /tefenua/wms for monitor filtering
2021-12-02 01:25:02,053 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher@79a030f5] and 1 interceptors
2021-12-02 01:25:02,057 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[tefenua], available services were [CSWInfoImpl[My GeoServer CSW], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS]]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,057 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-12-02 01:25:02,058 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[tefenua], available services were [CSWInfoImpl[My GeoServer CSW], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS]]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,058 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Getting layers and styles from LAYERS and STYLES
2021-12-02 01:25:02,058 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - establishing raster style for tefenua:tht_img_2017_50cm
2021-12-02 01:25:02,059 INFO [org.geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] starting, processing through flow controllers
2021-12-02 01:25:02,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] checking flow controller BasicOWSController(wfs.getfeature.=application/msexcel,org.geoserver.flow.controller.SimpleThreadBlocker@595be232)
2021-12-02 01:25:02,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] passed flow controller BasicOWSController(wfs.getfeature.=application/msexcel,org.geoserver.flow.controller.SimpleThreadBlocker@595be232)
2021-12-02 01:25:02,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] checking flow controller org.geoserver.flow.controller.UserConcurrentFlowController@28b2ab21
2021-12-02 01:25:02,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.flow] - UserFlowController(6,GS_CFLOW_-4e0a300c:17d77cdeda4:-7ffe) queue size 1
2021-12-02 01:25:02,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.flow] - UserFlowController(6,GS_CFLOW_-4e0a300c:17d77cdeda4:-7ffe) total queues 1
2021-12-02 01:25:02,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] passed flow controller org.geoserver.flow.controller.UserConcurrentFlowController@28b2ab21
2021-12-02 01:25:02,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] checking flow controller BasicOWSController(wms.getmap,org.geoserver.flow.controller.SimpleThreadBlocker@731305cc)
2021-12-02 01:25:02,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] passed flow controller BasicOWSController(wms.getmap,org.geoserver.flow.controller.SimpleThreadBlocker@731305cc)
2021-12-02 01:25:02,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] checking flow controller BasicOWSController(gwc,org.geoserver.flow.controller.SimpleThreadBlocker@bcca4c3)
2021-12-02 01:25:02,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] passed flow controller BasicOWSController(gwc,org.geoserver.flow.controller.SimpleThreadBlocker@bcca4c3)
2021-12-02 01:25:02,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] checking flow controller GlobalFlowController(org.geoserver.flow.controller.SimpleThreadBlocker@d809dfa)
2021-12-02 01:25:02,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] passed flow controller GlobalFlowController(org.geoserver.flow.controller.SimpleThreadBlocker@d809dfa)
2021-12-02 01:25:02,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] checking flow controller RateFlowController [wps.execute, action=Delay excess requests 30000ms]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] passed flow controller RateFlowController [wps.execute, action=Delay excess requests 30000ms]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,059 INFO [org.geoserver.flow] - Request control-flow performed, running requests: 1, blocked requests: 0
2021-12-02 01:25:02,060 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[tefenua], available services were [CSWInfoImpl[My GeoServer CSW], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS]]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,060 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[tefenua], available services were [CSWInfoImpl[My GeoServer CSW], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS]]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,060 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[tefenua], available services were [CSWInfoImpl[My GeoServer CSW], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS]]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,060 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[tefenua], available services were [CSWInfoImpl[My GeoServer CSW], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS]]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,060 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[tefenua], available services were [CSWInfoImpl[My GeoServer CSW], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS]]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,060 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[tefenua], available services were [CSWInfoImpl[My GeoServer CSW], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS]]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,060 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[tefenua], available services were [CSWInfoImpl[My GeoServer CSW], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS]]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,060 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms] - setting up map
2021-12-02 01:25:02,061 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms] - setting up 768x614 image
2021-12-02 01:25:02,061 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[tefenua], available services were [CSWInfoImpl[My GeoServer CSW], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS]]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,062 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[tefenua], available services were [CSWInfoImpl[My GeoServer CSW], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS]]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,062 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[tefenua], available services were [CSWInfoImpl[My GeoServer CSW], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS]]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,062 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[tefenua], available services were [CSWInfoImpl[My GeoServer CSW], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS]]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,062 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[tefenua], available services were [CSWInfoImpl[My GeoServer CSW], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS]]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,063 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[tefenua], available services were [CSWInfoImpl[My GeoServer CSW], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS]]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,063 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[tefenua], available services were [CSWInfoImpl[My GeoServer CSW], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS]]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,252 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms] - Direct rendering path produced the following image chain:
JAI op: Mosaic(it.geosolutions.jaiext.mosaic.MosaicOpImage) at Level: 0, offset:0, 0, size:768 x 614, tile size:768 x 614
Params. Parameter 1:MOSAIC_TYPE_BLEND; Parameter 2:[PlanarImage[minX=0 minY=0 width=768 height=614 tileGridXOffset=0 tileGridYOffset=0 tileWidth=384 tileHeight=614 sampleModel=java.awt.image.PixelInterleavedSampleModel@1070005 colorModel=ColorModel: #pixelBits = 8 numComponents = 1 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@7d332f8e transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false]]; Parameter 3:[javax.media.jai.ROI@9e6a62e]; Parameter 4:[[0.0]]; Parameter 5:[255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0]; Parameter 6:[RangeDouble[-Infinity, 0.0)]; 
Bands: 4, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel, transparency: Translucent
Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@1b0dc397
Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2a83f786<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
Number of sources: 1
   JAI op: Format(com.sun.media.jai.opimage.CopyOpImage) at Level: 1, offset:0, 0, size:768 x 614, tile size:384 x 614
   Params. Parameter 1:0; 
   Bands: 4, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel, transparency: Translucent
   Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@1b0dc397
   Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2a83f786<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
   Number of sources: 1
      JAI op: Scale(it.geosolutions.jaiext.scale.ScaleNearestOpImage) at Level: 2, offset:0, 0, size:768 x 614, tile size:768 x 614
      Params. Parameter 1:0.86173916; Parameter 2:0.8617348; Parameter 3:-0.054283; Parameter 4:-0.24900699; Parameter 5:InterpolationNearest; Parameter 6:javax.media.jai.ROI@4ada93ea; Parameter 7:false; Parameter 8:null; Parameter 9:null; 
      Bands: 4, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel, transparency: Translucent
      Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@1b0dc397
      Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2a83f786<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
      Number of sources: 1
         JAI op: BandMerge(it.geosolutions.jaiext.bandmerge.BandMergeOpImage) at Level: 3, offset:0, 0, size:891 x 713, tile size:512 x 512
         Params. Parameter 1:[null, null]; Parameter 2:0.0; Parameter 3:null; Parameter 4:null; Parameter 5:true; 
         Bands: 4, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel, transparency: Translucent
         Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@1b0dc397
         Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2a83f786<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
         Number of sources: 2
            JAI op: Mosaic(it.geosolutions.jaiext.mosaic.MosaicOpImage) at Level: 4, offset:0, 0, size:891 x 713, tile size:512 x 512
            Params. Parameter 1:MOSAIC_TYPE_OVERLAY; Parameter 2:null; Parameter 3:[javax.media.jai.ROI@1d8c40fb]; Parameter 4:[[0.0]]; Parameter 5:[0.0]; Parameter 6:[RangeDouble[-Infinity, 0.0)]; 
            Bands: 3, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel, transparency: Opaque
            Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@1b0dc397
            Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2a83f786<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
            Number of sources: 1
               JAI op: Scale(it.geosolutions.jaiext.scale.ScaleNearestOpImage) at Level: 5, offset:-1, -1, size:892 x 715, tile size:512 x 512
               Params. Parameter 1:1.0; Parameter 2:1.0000088; Parameter 3:-0.6992094; Parameter 4:-0.5000044; Parameter 5:InterpolationNearest; Parameter 6:null; Parameter 7:false; Parameter 8:null; Parameter 9:null; 
               Bands: 3, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel, transparency: Opaque
               Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@1b0dc397
               Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2a83f786<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
               Number of sources: 1
                  JAI op: ImageRead(com.sun.media.jai.imageioimpl.ImageReadOpImage) at Level: 6, offset:0, 0, size:892 x 714, tile size:512 x 512
                  Params. Parameter 1:FileImageInputStreamExtImpl which points to /img/tht_img_2017_50cm.tif; Parameter 2:1; Parameter 3:false; Parameter 4:false; Parameter 5:false; Parameter 6:null; Parameter 7:null; Parameter 8:[class it.geosolutions.imageio.imageioimpl.EnhancedImageReadParam    SourceRegion(Rectangle)[x:22551, y:3622, width:892, height:714]     SourceSubsampling[ssx:1, ssy:1]     DestinationOffset(Point)[x:0, y:0]]; Parameter 9:it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader@56e90590; 
                  Bands: 3, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel, transparency: Opaque
                  Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@1b0dc397
                  Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2a83f786<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
                  Number of sources: 0
            JAI op: Lookup(it.geosolutions.jaiext.lookup.LookupOpImage) at Level: 4, offset:0, 0, size:891 x 713, tile size:512 x 512
            Params. Parameter 1:it.geosolutions.jaiext.lookup.LookupTable@6a021eb5; Parameter 2:0.0; Parameter 3:null; Parameter 4:null; Parameter 5:false; 
            Bands: 1, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel, transparency: Opaque
            Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@1b0dc397
            Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2a83f786<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
            Number of sources: 1
               JAI op: and(com.sun.media.jai.opimage.AndOpImage) at Level: 5, offset:0, 0, size:891 x 713, tile size:512 x 512
               Params. 
               Bands: 1, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.IndexColorModel, transparency: Opaque
               Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@1b0dc397
               Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2a83f786<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
               Number of sources: 2
                  JAI op: Scale(it.geosolutions.jaiext.scale.ScaleGeneralOpImage) at Level: 6, offset:-1, -1, size:892 x 715, tile size:512 x 512
                  Params. Parameter 1:1.0; Parameter 2:1.0000088; Parameter 3:-0.6992094; Parameter 4:-0.5000044; Parameter 5:InterpolationNearest; Parameter 6:null; Parameter 7:false; Parameter 8:null; Parameter 9:null; 
                  Bands: 1, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.IndexColorModel, transparency: Opaque
                  Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@1b0dc397
                  Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2a83f786<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
                  Number of sources: 1
                     JAI op: VectorBinarize(it.geosolutions.jaiext.vectorbin.VectorBinarizeOpImage) at Level: 7, offset:0, 0, size:892 x 714, tile size:512 x 512
                     Params. minx:0; miny:0; width:892; height:714; geometry:POLYGON ((0 0, 0 714, 892 714, 892 0, 0 0)); antiAliasing:false; 
                     Bands: 1, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.IndexColorModel, transparency: Opaque
                     Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@1b0dc397
                     Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2a83f786<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
                     Number of sources: 0
                  Non op: class javax.media.jai.WritableRenderedImageAdapter at Level: 6, offset:0, 0, size:891 x 713, tile size:891 x 713
                  Bands: 1, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.IndexColorModel, transparency: Opaque
                  Tile cache: null
                  Tile scheduler: null
2021-12-02 01:25:02,257 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
    Angle = 0.0
    BaseUrl = http://54.203.222.2:8080/geoserver/
    Bbox = SRSEnvelope[-149.42840695381165 : -149.4201672077179, -17.520757913589478 : -17.5141704082489]
    BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
    Buffer = 0
    Clip = null
    CQLFilter = null
    Crs = GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
    SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
  PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
  UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
  AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
    Elevation = []
    Env = {}
    Exceptions = application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage
    FeatureId = null
    FeatureVersion = null
    Filter = null
    Format = image/jpeg
    FormatOptions = {}
    Get = true
    Height = 614
    Interpolations = []
    Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@f099f78d]
    MaxFeatures = null
    Palette = null
    RawKvp = {EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage, REQUEST=GetMap, FORMAT=image/jpeg, SRS=EPSG:4326, BBOX=-149.42840695381165,-17.520757913589478,-149.4201672077179,-17.5141704082489, VERSION=1.1.1, STYLES=, SERVICE=WMS, WIDTH=768, HEIGHT=614, TRANSPARENT=true, LAYERS=tefenua:tht_img_2017_50cm}
    RemoteOwsType = null
    RemoteOwsURL = null
    Request = GetMap
    RequestCharset = UTF-8
    ScaleMethod = null
    Sld = null
    SldBody = null
    SldVersion = null
    SortBy = null
    SortByArrays = null
    SRS = EPSG:4326
    StartIndex = null
    StyleBody = null
    StyleFormat = sld
    Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=raster]]
    StyleUrl = null
    StyleVersion = null
    Tiled = false
    TilesOrigin = null
    Time = []
    Transparent = true
    ValidateSchema = false
    Version = 1.1.1
    ViewParams = null
    Width = 768
2021-12-02 01:25:02,259 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[tefenua], available services were [CSWInfoImpl[My GeoServer CSW], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS]]
2021-12-02 01:25:02,260 DEBUG [org.geoserver.map.turbojpeg] - Encoding input image to write out as JPEG using .
2021-12-02 01:25:02,260 DEBUG [org.geoserver.map.turbojpeg] - Creating a TURBO JPEG writer and configuring it.
2021-12-02 01:25:02,260 DEBUG [org.geoserver.map.turbojpeg] - Writing image out...
2021-12-02 01:25:02,260 TRACE [org.geoserver.jai] - Recycling tile miss on type:1, banks: 1,414,656, arrayLength: {3}
...
2021-12-02 01:25:02,879 TRACE [org.geoserver.jai] - Recycling tile hit on type:1, banks: 32,768, arrayLength: {3}
2021-12-02 01:25:02,879 TRACE [org.geoserver.jai] - Recycling tile hit on type:1, banks: 32,768, arrayLength: {3}
2021-12-02 01:25:02,879 TRACE [org.geoserver.jai] - Recycling tile hit on type:1, banks: 32,768, arrayLength: {3}
2021-12-02 01:25:02,880 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton, this issue doesn't happen when rendering a single tile, it happens on few tiles when rendering tens of them, so I couldn't manage to isolate the relevant part of the huge generated log file. Is there a way to parametrize the log with only relevant information?

Comment: the bit at the end of the log file when the error has just occurred will be the relevant part

Comment: Hi @IanTurton, I finally got some time to work on the issue. I've attached the log as you requested. I could reproduce the issue on a fresh geoserver using both JAI Tiling Recycling and Transparent footprint behaviour. I confirm removing recycling solves the issue on my dev environment.

Comment: Tile recycling is something we have considered just dropping, it didn't provide performance benefits in load tests. As with other things, it's still there because there are more pressing things to work on.